# Create new Columns from Categories based on groupby data

Tags: python, pandas

I have the run
`df.groupby('position')['Category'].value_counts()`
and i get the below o/p:

```
    Categories  Count
val1    Cat_1   1
val2    Cat_2   3
        Cat_3   2
val3    Cat_3   1
val4    Cat_2   1
val5    Cat_1   2
```

I want to reconstruct the output like below using pandas

```
Positions   Cat_1   Cat_2   Cat_3
val1           1        0       0
val2           0        3       2
val3           0        0       1
val4           0        1       0
val5           2        0       0
```

Comment: Try `df.unstack().fillna(0)`?

Comment: This didn't help me, but unstack() method idea triggered. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with `fill_value=0` parameter:

```
df1 = df.groupby('position')['Category'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```